# How to get member of a generic list, stack and map in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

In Java, you could do this:

To get a member of a generic list:

```
public T getMember(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}
```

To get a member of a generic stack:

```
public T getMemberFromStack(int index){
     return stack.get(index); 
}
```

And to get a member of a generic map:

```
public T getMemberFromMap(K key){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

I have been looking through

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

But I could not find a similar method in C#.

These methods should return the objects without removing them from list/stack/map.

Comment: Stacks use push/pop, Lists are just accessors, aka `myList[index]`, and maps (dictionaries) use keys `myMap[key]`.

Comment: Is there no way to see an element from a stack, without removing it?

Comment: You can use the [Peek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w32446f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method but that will only show you the item at the top of the Stack. (Same with Queue, which will show the item at the beginnig of the queue without removing it)

Comment: @WilhelmSorban Sure - use [`Stack.Peek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w32446f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is all covered in the documentation of all the different types of collections.  For example, List<T> can be indexed, so myList[5] gets the element at index 5.  Same for a map--myDictionary[theKey].  What's the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

For `List<T>`:

```
public T GetMember(int index)
{
    return list[index];
}
```

For `Stack<T>` (***Why would you ever get a specific element on a stack?***):

```
public T GetMemberFromStack(int index)
{
    return stack.ElementAt(index);
}
```

For `Dictionary<T, K>`:

```
public T GetMemberFromMap(K key)
{
    return map[key];
}
```

Comment: Just a clarification, the `ElementAt` method is from `System.Linq` and not part of the default `Stack/Queue` classes so you may need to import that namespace (although a Stack/Queue may not be the best data structure for random access via an indexer).

Comment: @keyboardP Agreed. `Stack` itself does not offer such method (this is intended), because if it would, the point of a stack would be useless. If you were to retrieve elements by index, then you would use some kind of list.

Comment: I know, but it needs to behave like a stack, and at some point, print out (.toString) all the elements.

Comment: @WilhelmSorban If you're just printing out all the elements, you can use a simple foreach loop on the collection, since all those collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Java, C# allows you to overload *operators*. That is what the library designers did: rather than providing `get(int)` or `get(K)` methods, they provided an overload for the `[]` operator:

```
public T getMember(int index){
    return list[index];
}

public T getMemberFromMap(K key){
    return map[key];
}
```

An important difference between Java's `Map<K,V>` and C#'s `Dictionary<K,V>` is that Java's `get` would return `null` for a missing key, while C#'s [`operator []` would throw an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx).